HTTP Status 404 – Не найдено как исправить

Я не могу вывести Hello world, а хотя вчера запускалось.
pom.xml(ExEE):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExEE</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ExEE</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.10.0</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

HelloApplication.java:
import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class HelloApplication extends Application {

}

HelloResource:
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/hello-world")
public class HelloResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}

Конфигурация Apache Tomcat 10.1.26

Ещё, у меня нету шаблона для создания servlet.

Если используется версия Tomcat 10.x, то нельзя использовать зависимость
<dependency>           
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>

Эта версия сервлетов не поддерживается на сервере.
Ошибка 404 указывает на то, что ресурс не найден. Потому, что к url нужно добавить /api/hello-world.
Про аннотации и как указывать путь к классу можно почитать здесь.

HTTP Status 404 – Не найдено
Type Status Report
Message The requested resource [/Ex_war_exploded/] is not available
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

На картинке и в pom.xml стоит ExEE. Нужно синхронизировать конфигурацию maven и IDEA.

я поменял проект потому что яя разозлился, но создал новый

Если дочитал до конца ссылку, которую я оставил в ответе, то там есть архетип jaxrs-service-archetype, который можно использовать как заготовку проекта.
